# create an array of long

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create an array of long in java, but eclipse is showing me an error as shown below:

Below is my code:

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Can't i create a long size array in java?

Comment: No you can't but 2^31-1 elements should be enough (2147483647) How man memory do you have to store more than that amount of array elements?

Comment: @Scott : you will need an array of arrays. One of the shortfalls of java is indexes for lists and arrays are int not number so cannot be extended.

Comment: @MrSmith42: i need an array of 10^9 elements

Comment: You could use `Map<Long, Long>` instead

Comment: @SteveKuo do you realize how much memory a dense `Map<Long, Long>` would use?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Arrays of longs are fine: `long[]`. But *all* **arrays are `int`-indexed.** So just change `long n` to `int n` in the method parameter declaration, and you'll be all set.

Comment: if i want to create an array of 10^9 index, then how can i create it?

Comment: You cannot, by virtue of the fact that arrays are int-indexed. Why do you need to store so many `long`s in a single array? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: is there Any other way if i can store such a large amount of value else where?

Comment: Sure, there are _tons_ of ways to store large amounts of information - like a database (relational, document-oriented, etc.). But I suspect there is a _smarter_ algorithm you could apply.

Comment: Even if you could, a long array with 10^9 indices would require about 8 GB of memory...

Comment: He also needs change the method to return an array of long, not just a long.

Comment: @ErikNedwidek no... `m` is a `long[]`, so `m[n-1]` is a `long`. What's the problem?

Comment: To store more than what int gives you, you need to use a 2D array.

Comment: @ErikNedwidek: i'm returning an last element here.. not array

Comment: @MattBall, You're right. I've got two people on Ventrilo talking at me.

Answer (score 2):

> i need an array of 10^9 elements

You can create an array of one billion using an `int` value.  Make `n` an int, and you can create an array with `new long[n]`  Note: this will use 8 GB of heap.

Since you are building all the elements using a formula, you should be able to give all the values dynamically. i.e. create a component which is a "virtual" array which would save you having to generate an array of them all.

The reason I point this out is that the second loop is likely to take minutes at best if `k` is very small, or could easily take days.

BTW: I can't see all the code, but it appears you never need more than `k+1` values which can be allocated once instead of `n-k` times.

Comment: (Plus 1), hoping to find out more about `this will use 8 GB of heap.`

Comment: @jumping_monkey Each long uses 8 bytes, and one billion uses 8 billion bytes or 8 GB.

Answer (score 1):

For index you have to use `int` but not `long`

Answer (score 0):

`n` (the array capacity) has to be an `integer` not `long`

Answer (score 0):

You have my sympathy. We go through this every time memory sizes increase. There is a strange expectation that **this** time array sizes will not need to increase in parallel with memory sizes.

Your best solution is probably to write your own class with `long get(long index)` and `void set(long value, long index)` methods. It could represent the data as a long[10][1000000000], and encapsulate the mapping between the natural long index and the actual pair of int indices.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that array size is always equal to int size.
if you specify the array size more than 2147483647 you will get error.
long n;
long a[]=new long[n];
this will create error because long n exceeds 2147483647.
if int n then no error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    long[] arr = new long[n];//Just declare the size of array of int type , because we cannot declare the size of array as long type ,rather we can store the long type in it ,This code will fix the error .

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=sc.nextLong();
    }
    for(long i:arr)
     {
        System.out.print(i+" ");
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The index needs to be int so I convert long to int.

```
long n = sc.nextLong();
long[] arr = new long[(int)n];
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32931107)

Comment: This is the right answer. I have checked and then answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, I got your point. My Answer can solve the problem but this is the wrong way. because he can use int instead of converting long to int.