# Why this code showing error in my netbeans?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I use this code in my class. but its shows the error. why we cant assign long value in the String array declaration? It showing possible loss converstion.

```
long n=10000000;
String ar[]=new String[n];
```

Comment: try String[] ar=new String[n];

Comment: Nearly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071858/java-creating-byte-array-whose-size-is-represented-by-a-long which clearly indicates that you can only use int for array length-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct declaration. Use `int` instead of `long`. The Java JVM does not allow creating array in the size, range of `long` data type, so it is producing the warning (error) at the compile time.

```
int n=10000000;
String ar[]=new String[n];
```

I tried the following code:

```
public class Array {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int a[] = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
  }
}
```

Got the following exception:  `Requested array size exceeds VM limit`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
    at gen2dArray.main(Array.java:7)
```

Comment: why i cannot assign long value. if my n value is very big like long value. then i need to assign long value in string array. but it wont take it.

Comment: @Ram I think it will throw `OutOfMemoryError:` error. Check this out: [Do Java arrays have a maximum size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size).

Comment: it wont throw any exception. i cannot run it. because while typing it showing error in the netbeans and eclipse also.

Comment: @Ram because the compiler is warning you in advance. Even if you create an array of Integer.MAX_VALUE then will not warn you but fail at the runtime.

Comment: @Ram The Java Language specification prevents you from using `long` to declare the size of arrays

Answer (score 1):

This question is likely the same as this

[create an array of long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571557/create-an-array-of-long)

It is related to memory allocation. 
But we can use multi dimensional array to handle this.

On maximum integer array of string will take a huge amount of Memory.

Try use HashMap if you need to use large of array.