# Confused of the error when creating a long array using a long variable as its size

Tags: java, performance

My program needs to handle very big numbers as input, so I chose `long`. I have a error when I create an `array` of type `long` using a variable of type `long` as its size. Could someone please provide some insight about what went wrong here?

Error:

```
long[] Arr = new long[n];
                      ^    //incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int
```

Code:

```
private static long foo(long n, long m) {
  if (n <= 1) return n;
  long[] Arr = new long[n];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you'd ever need 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 slots of data anytime soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571557/create-an-array-of-long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571557/create-an-array-of-long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `n` is of type Long. But the length of an Array can only be an `int`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle very big numbers in your program, consider using BigInteger or BigDecimal types. These types have no theoretical  limit and allocate a much memory as needed. So it's limited only the amount of available memory.